# Parse Can't set channels for a query-targeted push

Tags: android, parse-platform, push-notification

**ERROR** :  **Parse** **Can't set channels for a query-targeted push.**

**Code**

```
    ParsePush push = new ParsePush();
    push.setChannel(AppConfig.PARSE_CHANNEL);
    push.setMessage("The Message");
    push.sendInBackground(new SendCallback() {
        @Override
        public void done(ParseException e) {
            if(e==null)
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"success",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: did u find any solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

You should use ParseQuery instead channel for targeting pushes. Try this:

```
    ParseQuery<ParseInstallation> query = ParseInstallation.getQuery();
    query.whereEqualTo("deviceToken", token); // recipient of your push. you can find this token in Installation table of your Parse.com app

    ParsePush push = new ParsePush();
    push.setQuery(query);
    push.setMessage("hi");
    push.sendInBackground(new SendCallback() {
        @Override
        public void done(ParseException e) {
            if (e != null)
                e.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
```

Comment: This worked for me, Thanks.
How to use Channels filed in query. I tried with following code
query.whereEqualTo("Channels", "Gaints");

This is not working for me. I think its becuase Channels field is defined in ParseInstallation object as Array. Can you please help me how to use where condition on Channels filed.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to GrafOrlov answer, to query multiple channel you can use whereContainsAll method. Like this:

```
String[] listOfAnimals = { "cat", "dog" };
ParseQUery pushQuery = ParseInstallation.getQuery();
pushQuery.whereContainsAll("channels", Arrays.asList(listOfAnimals));

ParsePush push = new ParsePush();
push.setQUery(pushQuery);
```